# Null bundle in fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments

I am writing a simple Kotlin  app and I want to send data from LessonsModule1Fragment to DetailsFragment and try to pass bundle variables. Depending on the position, the fragment should be inflated with the appropriate layout.

I'm trying to pass a position between fragments, but I always get null

**LessonsModule1Fragment**

```
class LessonsModule1Fragment : Fragment(), OnLessonClickListener {

private var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager? = null
private var adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewLessonAdapter.ViewHolder>? = null

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val binding = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_module1_lessons, container, false)

    val recyclerView = binding.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.lesson_recycler_view)
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
    adapter = RecyclerViewLessonAdapter(this)
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter

    return binding
}

override fun lessonClick(lesson: Lesson, position: Int) {
    var bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putInt("POSITION", position)

    var transaction = this.parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    var fragment = DetailsFragment()
    fragment.arguments = bundle
    transaction.replace(R.id.lesson_recycle_layout, fragment).commit()

    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_lessonsModule1Fragment_to_detailsFragment)
}
```

**DetailsFragment**

```
class DetailsFragment : Fragment()  {

private var num: Int? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

    num = arguments?.getInt("POSITION")

   when (num) {
       0 -> return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false)
       1 -> return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details2, container, false)
       2 -> return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details3, container, false)
   }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false)
}}
```

**RecyclerViewLessonAdapter**

```
class RecyclerViewLessonAdapter (private val lessonClickListener: OnLessonClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewLessonAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

private val lessons = DataStorage.getLessonsList()

inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) :  RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val itemTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lesson_title)
    val itemDetails: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lesson_description)
    val itemImage: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lesson_image)

    fun lessonBind(lesson: Lesson, clickListener: OnLessonClickListener) {
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            clickListener.lessonClick(lesson, adapterPosition)
        }
    }

}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.lesson_card, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(v)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.itemImage.setImageResource(lessons[position].images)
    holder.itemTitle.text = lessons[position].title
    holder.itemDetails.text = lessons[position].details

    val lesson = lessons[position]
    holder.lessonBind(lesson, lessonClickListener)
}

override fun getItemCount() = lessons.size
}
```

**OnLessonClickListener**

```
interface OnLessonClickListener {
fun lessonClick(lesson: Lesson, position: Int)
}
```

Perhaps there is a more suitable way?

Comment: You seem to be navigating twice here, once manually with the transaction, then with the navigation component? The navigation component replaces the need for managing your own transactions. If you want to use it, get rid of the duplicate transaction and pass the arguments with the navigation controller.

Comment: Oh thank you! I solved this question with a couple of lines

Answer (score 0):

I used navigation arguments, added these lines and it worked. Thanks for the hint

```
        val action = LessonsModule1FragmentDirections.actionLessonsModule1FragmentToDetailsFragment(position)
    findNavController().navigate(action)
```